# How to add a count to resource id's

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if what i want is even possible.

Trying some coding for Android but i have a little issue and i hope someone can help me with this.

I have

```
ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circleselect1);
```

Now what is want is the Integer at the end of my resource id incremented with one

Like

```
ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circleselect+integer);
```

I know this is not working but is there a way to accomplice what i want?

Comment: Why would you like that? remember that those integers are auto-generated by the system and not guarente any order or value

Comment: I have a counter, and i have 4 R.id.circleselect's like R.id.circleselect1, R.id.circleselect2, R.id.circleselect3. R.id.circleselect4 i want to get the right source if the counter hits the next int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw your comment `I have a counter, and i have 4 R.id.circleselect's like R.id.circleselect1, R.id.circleselect2, R.id.circleselect3. R.id.circleselect4 i want to get the right source if the counter hits the next int`and the solution you are asking for is a bad idea.

Instead try this one out. Create an array of the ID's that you want and then use them as you want.

```
int[] array = new int[]{R.id.circleselect1,R.id.circleselect2,R.id.circleselect3,R.id.circleselect4};
```

Comment: You're my hero of the day, thanks for this explanation. It works fine for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

IDs as they appear in the `R` class (more precisely, in the `id` class inside `R`) are just static fields.

You can access them dynamically by using

```
R.id.class.getDeclaredField("circleselect" + i).getInt(null);
```

where `i` is the integer at the end of the name.

This is not advised as this is very un-OOP and will break if the field does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Something Like this?

```
String circle = "circleselect"  + integer; // or integer.toString()
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(circle, "id", getPackageName());
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(resID);
```